# Is there any api call to validate firebase serverkey and sender id?

Tags: firebase

I want to validate firebase server-key and sender id is valid or not. Can you please provide me is there any way to validate ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can validate firebase server key. follow the link below.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#checkAPIkey

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think such a call exists, as these keys are not meant to be distributed in an automated way. If you're uncertain if the key you have is correct, copy it from the Firebase console again to remove any doubt.

Comment: I mean, is there any max length or character validation to server key and sender id? It will help me a lot to complete my work.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's an API, nor are they document afaik. Maybe it'll be easier to help if you explain what you're trying to accomplish with this validation, instead of how to implement it. See [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).